# Python list popping and appending

Tags: python, list, sorting

I am learning python and have a working code (shown below). However, I would like to know if there's a better way to rewrite it below.

What I am trying to do is to match list A that is passed to a method against a predefined list B. If an item in list A contains an item in list B, I'd like to move it to the end of list A. Here's an example:

```
# example 1
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
sanitized_list = sanitize(a) # [3, 4, 5, 1, 2]

# example 2
a = [3, 6, 1, 7, 4]
sanitized_list = sanitize(a) # [3, 6, 7, 4, 1]


def sanitize(arg):
    # predefined list
    predefined_list = [1, 2]

    for item in predefined_list:
        try:
            # check to see if 'arg' contain any item
            # in the predefined list
            i = arg.index(item)

            # save the value of arg[i]
            j = arg[i]

            # remove "j" from "arg"
            arg.pop(i)

            # append item to end of "arg"
            arg.append(j)
        except ValueError:
            pass

    return arg
```

Comment: This question is probably better suited to http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: First thing I would do is use a different variable name for `list`. It is shadowing the default type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use sorting; simply sort on the result of a containment test; `False` is sorted before `True`, but your order otherwise remains stable. You can make `b` a set to make the containment test faster:

```
def sanitize(lst):
    # predefined list
    b = {1, 2}
    return sorted(lst, key=lambda v: v in b)
```

I made `b` a set here, but that is optional (but faster if you do).

So for each element in `lst`, if that element is in `b` sort it *after* anything that is *not* in `b`, but keep their relative order otherwise.

Note that rather than `list` I used a different name for the argument here; you don't want to shadow the built-in type.

Demo:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> def sanitize(lst):
...     # predefined list
...     b = {1, 2}
...     return sorted(lst, key=lambda v: v in b)
... 
>>> sanitize(a)
[3, 4, 5, 1, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Better to create always a new list:

```
def sanitize(l):
    b = set([1, 2])
    result = ([], [])
    for item in l:
        result[item in b].append(item)
    result[0].extend(result[1])
    return result[0]
```

Answer (score -1):

Operations between lists are easier if transform them into `sets`.

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

def sanitize(l):
    b = [1, 2]

    try:
        sanitized = list(set(l) - set(b)) + b
        return sanitized
    except ValueError:
        return None
```

Comment: What if it the argument is [1, 5, 6, 3]? The result should be [5, 6, 3, 1].